# Plotting points from two arrays to a graph

Tags: java, arrays, graph

I was solving tsp using simulated annealing and I want to plot the optimum distance versus temperature of the optimum distance and join those points to see the nature of the graph.

I've got the distances and temperatures in two different arrays now I need to plot this as a scatter. If putting the values in one array is required for plotting even that can be done but how do I plot such a graph. I tried using libre office to plot the graph but that isn't working at all, the app is crashing.

```java
while (temp > 1) {
     //some code giving distance
     // Cool system
     temp *= 1-coolingRate;
     System.out.println(""+ best.getDistance());
     System.out.println(""+ temp );
     //Outputs to be put in an array and plotted 
}





Edit 1: 
Both the arrays are single dimensional and the graph I want to plot has points whose X and y co ordinates are taken from these arrays consecutively.
I can't figure out a way to do it.
```

Comment: Could you add some additional context to your code example? What are the nature of the arrays you're plotting? What error are you receiving or why is the output unexpected?

Answer (score 0):

Search your code to see if 'temp' is defined in multiple ways in your code. temp is a common variable that is also often used as a temporary holding place while you crunch the numbers. Has it been previously defined?

Comment: No the program is running fine